# Simplifying $\sum_{j=k}^{n}\binom{j}{k}/(2^{k-1})$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

While doing an exercise (computing an expected value), I encountered an expression that looks like this. Is there a simpler formula?

$$ \sum_{j=k}^{n}\frac{\binom{j}{k}}{2^{k-1}} $$

If it wasn't for the denominator, I knew the solution.

Comment: Well then take the denominator out of the summation, it does not depend on the index of summation.

Comment: Now seeing it again after lunch, it's kind of obvious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that

$$\sum_{j=0}^a\binom{j}{k} = \binom{a+1}{k+1}$$
Then:
$$\sum_{j=k}^{n}\frac{\binom{j}{k}}{2^{k-1}} = \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\left[\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{j}{k}-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{j}{k}\right] = \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\left[\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{k}{k+1}\right] = $$

$$=\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

given that $$\binom{k}{k+1} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\large\begin{align}
\sum_{j=k}^{n}\frac{\binom{j}{k}}{2^{k-1}}
&=\frac 1{2^{k-1}}\sum_{j=k}^n \binom jk\\
&=\frac 1{2^{k-1}}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$$

NB - the summation can be taken from $j=k$ instead of from $j=0$ because $\binom jk=0$ for $j<k$.